# Change default style of all asp:HyperLink tags

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, hyperlink

He, I'm currently restyling a site that I'm working on.  It's a VS2013 project and I'm still getting the hang of using Visual Studio for web dev.

Currently the project has quite a lot of `<asp:HyperLink></asp:HyperLink>` tags

I know that I can use `<asp:HyperLink CssClass="testingCss"></asp:HyperLink>` to change the css of these HyperLinks in css using classes but there are so many links that I'd have to edit to fix this.  Is there any quicker way of dealing with this?  Like making a default text color property in my site's css file?

For example, the css used in p tags:

```
p {
  color:red;
}
```

I'm sure there has to be a way to do what I want to do like this p tag example I gave.  Would appreciate any help I can get here as it should save a lot of time and maintenance.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `a{color:red}` doesnt work?

Comment: It doesn't but thanks tim's answer I understand that it should work and I've been looking in the wrong direction for an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be a `<asp:HyperLink>` in your markup but when the page is rendered, this will be output as a regular HTML anchor - `<a>`

For this reason you can target it the same way you would any other anchor:

```
a { color:red }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's not working but if what you say is true then my problem probably has something to do with a conflict somewhere else.  This will help me in moving forward.

Comment: No problems. If it's not working, my guess would be that you have some other CSS included which is overriding your style. If you are using a modern browser - Chrome, Firefox, IE9+ - you can inspect HTML elements and see what CSS styles are being applied and where these styles originate from in code. Let me know if you need help further.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this code to your css
a{color:#ff0000}

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was the bootstrap css conflicting with my other css file.  I just changed the css in the bootstrap file to get what I wanted.  You guys were right to say that you just need to change the a tag for HyperLinks in asp.net projects.  Thanks for the help.